# How to install Windows Phone 7 on a Windows Phone 8 device?

Tags: 8.0, 7.x, nokia-lumia-930

I'm a fan of Windows Phone 7. Is it possible to downgrade a Windows Phone 8 device to Windows Phone 7? I got a Nokia Lumia 930.

Comment: Anything in particular that you want from 7.x that you can't find in 8.x?

Comment: If you are craving Windows Phone 7.x, I can exchange my Lumia 800 with you ;) No extra charges

Comment: WP8 is actually a completely new operating system, built on Windows NT, whereas WP7 was built on Windows CE (as was the previous Windows Mobile).  WP8 does not have the drivers to run on the hardware that was built for WP7.

Comment: Just downgrading to WP8.0 would probably be enough to keep you happy, but I don't think that's possible either. I too find WP8.1... disappointing. So just get used to 8.1 :-(

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible as Windows Phone 7 supported different processors.

Comment: I suspect it's more of an issue for drivers for other hardware components, than the processor itself - Both product ranges use Snapdragon processors running the Arm v7 instruction set, so you might want to expand your answer a little more, or add some references

Comment: WP7.x doesn't support multi-core processors; no support for [symmetric multi-processing (SMP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_multiprocessing), and consequently has no firmware/drivers for such CPUs. All WP8.x and W10M devices have multi-core CPUs. At best, you'd lose a lot of performance (although the demands of WP7.x were lower, too). More likely, it would probably fail to work with the CPU at all.

Answer (score 5):

This question was really unexpected!

Short answer: **no**.

Windows Phone 7's [last update](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_version_history#Windows_Phone_7.8) is dated back to 14 March 2013. Also, the last few updates didn't included new hardware support but only some software improvement.
Without hardware support there is no chance to get WP7 working on a Nokia Lumia 930. It's not only about processor or instruction set: screen resolution, new and faster cellular hardware, new sensors on board, etc. Basically all new hardware that wasn't available at the time when Windows Phone 7 was in development.
Since the release of Windows Phone 8 - that was nearly two years ago! - all the Nokia Lumia phones come equipped with the new version of the OS.

Frankly, doing such downgrade, even if possible, would be highly **inadvisable**. You would be unable to install lots of applications (even Microsoft has pulled the plug of WP7 and doesn't update [Skype](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34489/is-skype-for-windows-phone-7-being-discontinued) anymore) and you would missing hundreds of Windows Phone 8.1's new features.

If you really like WP7 (and retroware attract you: WP7 support ends *today*), have a look on the internet: you can surely get for a cheap price a WP7 device for playing around, but I firmly suggest to enjoy WP8.1 for your daily smartphone needs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a .bsp file for it.  The same as if you were installing windows ce 5.0 or 6.0.  That way the OS knows how to deal with the hardware..  From there, you can build the image and (somehow) upload it to the phone.  You have to have a copy of the build environment, or know someone who does.

I went thru the same crap with my Lumia. (unsure of the model because i paid 20 dollars for it from a friend and it just sits here with the battery out)   I want either windows mobile 6.5.5 on it or even windows ce 6.0  CE6 would be the best because it's got a start menu and real windows not just that fullscreen crap.  (I can't stand that fullscreen list view or the modern/metro lego block screen that all new windows OSs have.  when I got the phone I asked "can I install classic shell on it? lol.")

Never was going to use mine for a phone or gps, I just wanted a cheap windows ce based PDA and was told it was possible.  (I should have figured it wasn't probable tho)  A windows CE image needs to be "built" for the specific device you are planning to use it on (or one similar enough to run decent and not brick)

If you don't care about everything working 100%, it might be possible.  Especially if you can find a group of people who share the same desires to downgrade and have moderate windows CE building skills.

Android might be easier to get running since its open source and free.  From there, you can probably emulate a windows 7 phone but it won't be running natively.

Give it a few years (like I'm doing), maybe when it's "old hardware" a scene might pop up with that specific goal in mind and the resources to pull it off...  Or just find the closest model with phone 7 and try to reflash it (praying it don't brick along the way)